# Visual Studio 2013 generates a Backup folder in each build for visual C++ project

Tags: visual-c++

I use VC2013 to build and run a VC++ project. It works well, but in each single time I open and build the VC++ project, there will be a folder named like "Backup, Backup1, Backup2, Backup3,..." automatically generated by the VC2013. In the backup folder, there is just a ".sln" file.

Anyone can tell how to stop this automatical process? and what is the function of the backup folder for?

Comment: This is normally only done once, when the project is automatically upgraded from an earlier version of Visual Studio. Does it prompt you to upgrade when you open it?

Comment: Yes, but why it always prompt me a one-way upgrade the VC++ project? Isn't it done for all? Or I do not upgrade it?